# Tooltip not populating: D3 stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js, stacked

I am going crazy trying to get the description field to populate in the tooltip. If anyone can help me understand why it won't work, I would very much appreciate the insight. I posted the data first, then the script

Data:

```
Dates    Meals & Entertainment  Hotels  Travel  Misc    descrip
Jan-12  406.78  0   0   0   "DESCRIPTION"
Feb-12  0   0   0   0   0
Mar-12  0   466.2   0   0   
Apr-12  0   534.5   0   0   
May-12  189.9   129.92  0   0   
Jun-12  146.83  0   0   0   
Jul-12  117.65  0   0   0   
Aug-12  0   0   0   0   
Sep-12  169.02  122.84  0   0   
Oct-12  182.86  0   0   0   
Nov-12  0   229.95  0   0   
Dec-12  0   114.12  0   0   
Jan-13  100.63  0   0   0   
Feb-13  0   0   0   0   
Mar-13  136.61  469.53  0   0   
Apr-13  0   446.5   0   0   
May-13  169.22  758.14  0   0   
Jun-13  0   0   0   0   
Jul-13  1   0   0   0   0
Aug-13  0   280.28  0   0   
Sep-13  182.38  0   0   0   
Oct-13  65.26   0   0   0   
Nov-13  158.6   0   0   0   
Dec-13  813.87  0   0   231.24  
Jan-14  158.86  0   0   0   
Feb-14  0   0   0   0   
Mar-14  64.35   658.06  0   0   
Apr-14  255.44  507.24  0   0   
May-14  134.93  0   0   0   
Jun-14  592.57  0   0   0   
Jul-14  50.7    0   0   0   
Aug-14  0   0   0   0   
Sep-14  110.79  0   0   0   
Oct-14  50  908.41  242.91  0   
Nov-14  0   0   0   0   
Dec-14  0   0   0   0
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div class = wrap>
    <div class = title><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <div class= main></div>
    </div>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 30},
    width = 970 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["4A5E40", "ACCD9D","ACCD9D","DBDBDA"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var tooltip = d3.select(".main").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select(".main").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;



  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Dates"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var descrip = +d.descrip;
    var y0 = 0;
    d.spending = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.spending[d.spending.length - 1].y1;
  });


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Dates; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
        .style("text-anchor", "start");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")


  var Dates = svg.selectAll(".Dates")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Dates) + ",0)"; });


  Dates.selectAll(".rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.spending; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {                                
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
               tooltip.html( "On " + d.y0)
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 65) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 80) + "px")
               d3.select(this).style("fill", "#B19330");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0),
               d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d) { return  color(d.name); });

      });



  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 895)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", "4A5E40");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 895)
      .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", "ACCD9D");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 895)
      .attr("y", 50)      
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", "DBDBDA");

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 865)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return "Meals & Entertainment"; });

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 865)
      .attr("y", 34)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return "Hotels & Travel"; });

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 865)
      .attr("y", 59)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return "Misc."; });      
});

</script>
```

Comment: The tsv data you added is not valid and the description column is empty for most of the rows. Do you want this data to be added to the tooltip? Something like `On 0 Description: DESCRIPTION`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for the data.tsv because the tabulation is wrong, try importing what you pasted into Google Sheets to see what I mean. Also your html is wrong you're missing the body tags and the closing html tags, but I don't think that's the reason you're not seeing your tooltip. You should open the [developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and see if there are any errors loading the file.

Comment: I figured it out. the + in 'var d.descrip = +d.descrip'  needed to be removed and I needed to add descrip: descrip to d.spending

Answer (score 1):

Hope this sample code helps.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 90,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 970 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["4A5E40", "ACCD9D", "ACCD9D", "DBDBDA"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var tooltip = d3.select(".main").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select(".main").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var data = [{
  "Dates": "Jan-12",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 406.78,
  "Hotels & Travel": 0,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}, {
  "Dates": "Feb-12",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 0,
  "Hotels & Travel": 0,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}, {
  "Dates": "Mar-12",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 0,
  "Hotels & Travel": 466.2,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}, {
  "Dates": "Apr-12",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 0,
  "Hotels & Travel": 534.5,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}, {
  "Dates": "May-12",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 189.9,
  "Hotels & Travel": 139.92,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}, {
  "Dates": "Jun-12 146.83 0",
  "Meals & Entertainment": 0,
  "Hotels & Travel": 0,
  "Misc": 0,
  "descrip": 0
}];



color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "Dates";
}));

data.forEach(function(d) {
  var descrip = +d.descrip;
  var y0 = 0;
  d.spending = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      descrip: descrip,
      y0: y0,
      y1: y0 += +d[name]
    };
  });
  d.total = d.spending[d.spending.length - 1].y1;
});


x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Dates;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("x", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
  .style("text-anchor", "start");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")


var Dates = svg.selectAll(".Dates")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.Dates) + ",0)";
  });


Dates.selectAll(".rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.spending;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y1);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    tooltip.html("On " + d.y0 + "Description : " + d.descrip)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 65) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 80) + "px")
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#B19330");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0),
      d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

  });



svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 895)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", "4A5E40");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 895)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", "ACCD9D");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 895)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", "DBDBDA");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 865)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Meals & Entertainment";
  });

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 865)
  .attr("y", 34)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Hotels & Travel";
  });

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 865)
  .attr("y", 59)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Misc.";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class=wrap>
  <div class=title>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=main></div>
```